# Wifi stops working after closing the lid/suspending linux

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 in my hp 340s G7 laptop and have chosen dual boot with both windows and ubuntu. whenever i close my lid/usethe suspend option on linux the wifi stops working and shows hardware airplane mode enabled how to fix this ?